# Writing connection pool for distributed environment in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, distributed-computing

Currently I'm using `hibernate c3p0` connection pooling for background processes which I have written in java. Now, we are shifting background process in a distributed environment.

My Question is, how can I write a connection pooling code so that any node in a distributed environment can access the `connection` object from that connection pool.

I'm using  `Apache Storm`  for distributed processing. I'm not thinking of writing code in each of the `Bolt` which has need to do some database operation.

Comment: Are you sure that each `Bolt` should even be handling a `Connection` anyway?

Comment: No. Each bolt is processing some task.that can be a database operation. I don't want each bolt should establish connection before doing any  database operation in each bolt.

Comment: So you basically want to share a Connection Pool between multiple hosts?

Comment: @R4J Yes. I want share connection pool across multiple host.

Comment: What are the reasons for sharing connection pool? I don't this its a good idea.

Comment: @sunrise76 so are you referring to create individual connection pool for each instance ?? I fear its the wrong practice.

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to share TCP/IP connections between multiple hosts. Each host has to have its own connection pool.

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis What I meant was that instead of each `Bolt` (that actually needs to access the database) having a `Connection` (or a pool), is that they would send the result to a distinct set of `Bolts` which would then have a small pool. Since the bottleneck is the database, there shouldn't be any (bad) performance differences between having 20 `Bolts` write to the database vs. having let's say 2 `Bolts` writing and 18 `Bolts` processing and delegating the results. That way you wouldn't need to write `Connection` processing in every `Bolt` you have.